# Cannot open layout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I just created a blank activity from File > New > Activity. Its `MainActivity.java` is editable, same for `menu_main.xml`, but the `activity_main.xml` layout file cannot be opened. There is no error message, no sign that anything is happening at all, nothing. I also tried removing the activity and creating it again.

Android Studio is updated to the latest version (1.2.1.1) and I tried opening and closing it.
I'm running it on Mac OS X 10.10.3 and the file exists on the file system where the IDE says it is.

Has anyone ever had this problem?

EDIT : Just tried restarting my computer and the same thing happens.

EDIT 2 : my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "ca.etsmtl.gti785.telebama"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2') {
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have had this issue after updating.  Have a look at your gradle and and make sure you download the latest SDK that match your gradle

Comment: Okay then I am assuming you have not downloaded the latest SDK for the buildToolsVersion "22.0.1".  You need to go to your SDK manager and download the latest version and tools.

Comment: They are already [downloaded and installed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3f5pa2nh3xpb3h/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-05-12%2020.56.07.png?dl=0).

Comment: Go down to extras and see if the support library is 22.1.1

Comment: It wasn't, but I just upgraded it and the same thing happens. I just saw a couple of available updates and I'm installing them right now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the problem is maybe in the selected preview API or device. Check out this toolbar in the preview.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Please clean & build you project.
2. Reload xml file go to src->main->res->layout->activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Rebuild, clean, restart mac, reinstall Android Studio, install different Android Studio versions... nothing worked.

Then I found out that **the problem was gradle, not Android Studio**. In gradle-wrapper.properties I **changed the version from 3.3 to 3.5**:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If any other project is open in any other window then close it. Now close current project too. Open that project on which you intend to work, first. 
You'll be good to go.